# How can I change this variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, session, variables

```
document.getElementById('user-name').onkeyup = function () {
    connection.extra['user-name'] = this.value;
};
document.getElementById('setup-voice-only-call').onclick = function () {
    this.disabled = true;
    connection.open();
};
connection.extra = {
    'user-name': 'Anonym'
};
```

I have a PHP website were users can login. I am using `$_SESSION['username']`.
How can I change the variable `user-name` as `session['username']` in the above JavaScript code?

Comment: embed the php value in the JS code at page generation time, or use an ajax request to fetch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to dynamically generate the javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
connection.extra = {
    'user-name': <?= json_encode($_SESSION['username']) ?>
};
</script>
</head>
...
```